# Headless point cloud sampling with docker

Tags: python, docker, render, pyglet

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.12-slim-buster
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-opengl wget
RUN pip install mesh-to-sdf
```

Build this docker image. Let's name it `test`.

```
docker build -t test .
```

Run and execute a container from this image.

```
docker run --name test -d -t test 
docker exec -it test bash
```

Inside the container, create the following 2 files, `mesh.obj` and `convert.py`. You could download them with the following commands:

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zshyang/9f4b18dea65ac5bba61a7fc2bbd98aa4/raw/9e681e2f9fa1bb3682fe8c95d8341b5b1e0f798a/mesh.obj
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zshyang/4cf826bc16c05038c2b4529422b82484/raw/4127b8a0d443e0f257a162a9b3278595ac94ea76/convert.py
```

```
f 1 2 3
v 1 1 1
v 1 2 3
v 1 9 0
```

```
import trimesh
import mesh_to_sdf
mesh = trimesh.load('mesh.obj')
mesh_to_sdf.sample_sdf_near_surface(mesh, number_of_points = 500000, surface_point_method='scan', sign_method='normal', scan_count=100, scan_resolution=400, sample_point_count=10000000, normal_sample_count=11, min_size=0, return_gradients=False)
```

Then by running `python convert.py` I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 4, in <module>
    mesh_to_sdf.sample_sdf_near_surface(mesh, number_of_points = 500000, surface_point_method='scan', sign_method='normal', scan_count=100, scan_resolution=400, sample_point_count=10000000, normal_sample_count=11, min_size=0, return_gradients=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mesh_to_sdf/__init__.py", line 59, in sample_sdf_near_surface
    surface_point_cloud = get_surface_point_cloud(mesh, surface_point_method, 1, scan_count, scan_resolution, sample_point_count, calculate_normals=sign_method=='normal' or return_gradients)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mesh_to_sdf/__init__.py", line 17, in get_surface_point_cloud
    return surface_point_cloud.create_from_scans(mesh, bounding_radius=bounding_radius, scan_count=scan_count, scan_resolution=scan_resolution, calculate_normals=calculate_normals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mesh_to_sdf/surface_point_cloud.py", line 162, in create_from_scans
    scans.append(Scan(mesh,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mesh_to_sdf/scan.py", line 61, in __init__
    color, depth = render_normal_and_depth_buffers(mesh, camera, self.camera_transform, resolution)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mesh_to_sdf/pyrender_wrapper.py", line 58, in render_normal_and_depth_buffers
    renderer = pyrender.OffscreenRenderer(resolution, resolution)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrender/offscreen.py", line 31, in __init__
    self._create()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrender/offscreen.py", line 149, in _create
    self._platform.init_context()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrender/platforms/pyglet_platform.py", line 50, in init_context
    self._window = pyglet.window.Window(config=conf, visible=False,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 171, in __init__
    super(XlibWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 590, in __init__
    display = pyglet.canvas.get_display()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/canvas/__init__.py", line 94, in get_display
    return Display()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/canvas/xlib.py", line 123, in __init__
    raise NoSuchDisplayException('Cannot connect to "%s"' % name)
pyglet.canvas.xlib.NoSuchDisplayException: Cannot connect to "None"
```

Do you konw anyway to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: My guess is that this has to do with the fact that a Docker container has no notion of a desktop, and therefore of a display.  I don't know the packages in question, but my guess would be that you need to do some kind of setup to either cause GL to not need a display or to create an offscreen buffer/display for it to work with.

Comment: @KlausD. : Thanks for point this out. I have uploaded the full error traceback.

Comment: @CryptoFool : Yes, I think your guess is correct! I have uploaded the detailed traceback. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at https://pyrender.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/offscreen.html !

Answer (score 2):

To get past the particular error you're getting, you have to set up a display for GL to use.  A simple way to do that is with Xvfb.

Add this line to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb
```

Then, in the container, before you run your script, run these commands to create an offscreen display buffer and set the DISPLAY env var to point to it:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -ac +extension GLX +render -noreset &> xvfb.log &
export DISPLAY=:1
```

When I do this and then run your code, I get a new error:

```
pyglet.gl.ContextException: Could not create GL context
```

I did some Googling and tried some things, but couldn't find an easy way to get past this error.  Threads I found surrounding this error message talked about two things: bugs in library code and GL versions.  I would suggest that if/when you get that error message, you Google it and look at what you get to see if you can figure out what you need to do next.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for trying to fix it. I tried this `xvfb` method as well. And get the same error as you've mentioned. And thanks for the general suggestion. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Cool.  As I did answer the question asked..."Do you konw anyway to solve THIS problem?",  I think it's appropriate to click the Check Mark to make it clear that your question was answered.

Comment: @CryptoFool I wasted a lot of time today trying to setup VirtualGL to run a PyOpenGL-based app in a docker container on a headless server. In the end, all I really needed was `xvfb`! Thanks for the suggestion. It works quite well!